# Can we add two or more attributes in one class of DataPatchInterface in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

In Magento 2.3 we can add product or customer attribute using DataPatchInterface. Most of the example I saw that people adding only one attribute in one class. So my question is.Is it possible to add more eav attributes in one class or do I have to make sperate classes for others?

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you. You may manipulate with as many attributes within one Data Patch as you wish.